# MongoDB c# using new driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, console

I know I may sound to you guys like a total nob but I am.
I am trying to use the mongodb driver in c#. Try to do something like add a record.

I learned today all basic mongodb queries and even tried it with robomongo.

But i don't understand how to use it in c#?
how to call it from the main function??

this is the code I wrote (trying to use mongodb website tutorial):

what is await? what is Task? what does it mean and how to make it work?

Thank you a lot for helping me.

```
class Program
{
    protected static IMongoClient _client;
    protected static IMongoDatabase _database;


    public static void Main()
    {
        _client = new MongoClient();
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
        Task simpleTask = Tasky();
    }
    public async Task Tasky()
    {
        var document = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "address" , new BsonDocument
                    {
                        { "street", "2 Avenue" },
                        { "zipcode", "10075" },
                        { "building", "1480" },
                        { "coord", new BsonArray { 73.9557413, 40.7720266 } }
                    }
                },
                { "borough", "Manhattan" },
                { "cuisine", "Italian" },
                { "grades", new BsonArray
                    {
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "date", new DateTime(2014, 10, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                            { "grade", "A" },
                            { "score", 11 }
                        },
                        new BsonDocument
                        {
                            { "date", new DateTime(2014, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc) },
                            { "grade", "B" },
                            { "score", 17 }
                        }
                    }
                },
                { "name", "Vella" },
                { "restaurant_id", "41704620" }
            };

                        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");
                        await collection.InsertOneAsync(document);
                    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to understand simpler version, then read about `async/await`. Add some documents to your collection using `mongo` shell and try this:

```
var collection = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost").GetServer()
        .GetDatabase("your_db").GetCollection<BsonDocument>("your_collection");
var cursor = collection.FindAll();
foreach(var doc in cursor) {
    Console.WriteLine(doc);
}
```

`cursor` is used to get documents one by one.